# Problems eagerloading a set of object using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using Turbogears2 and SQLAlchemy to develop a webapp. I have two mapped tables O1 and O2.
O2 has a sorted list of O1s in 'ones'.
At some point I want to query all O2's and the referenced O1's.

Unfortunately the query below fails because table O2 is aliased in the query and the column referenced by the order_by phrase is no longer known.

I'd like to know how I can fix this problem while, if possible, staying in the declarative syntax.

```
base = declarative_base()

class O1(base):
    __tablename__ = 'O1'
    value = Column(Integer)
    o2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('O1.id')) # The culprit

class O2(base):
    __tablename__ = 'O2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ones = relation('O1', order_by = ['O1.value'])


Session.query(O2).options(eagerload('ones')).all() # Throws an error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda of clause elements to achieve late binding of the order by, like this:

```
ones = relation('O1', order_by=lambda:[O1.value])
```

Or as an another option, make the whole order_by a string, like this:

```
ones = relation('O1', order_by='O1.value, O1.something_else')
```

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work. I'll use the second one. One addition because it is ambiguous: When using strings you have to use the mapper names. The 'O1' in the second example actually refers to the class, not the tablename.